# Compute the exact symbol error probability for this one dimensional graph

Tags: probability

Compute the exact symbol error probability.

[image]

This is decision area.

[image]

For this rightmost points and leftmost points.

$$\bigl(1-Q(\frac{A} {\sqrt{2 N_0}}) \bigl)^2$$

For three points in the middle.

$$\left[\bigl(1-Q(\frac{A} {\sqrt{2 N_0}}) \bigl)^2 \right]^3$$

So the total error probability

$$P_e = 1- \bigl(1-Q(\frac{A} {\sqrt{2 N_0}}) \bigl)^2 \left[\bigl(1-Q(\frac{A} {\sqrt{2 N_0}}) \bigl)^2 \right]^3$$

$$\Rightarrow P_e = 1- \left[\bigl(1-Q(\frac{A} {\sqrt{2 N_0}}) \bigl)^2 \right]^8$$

**Is this correct?
If not, what is the exact equation?**

Comment: That is incorrect. You just need to calculate the probability that the received point goes beyond the decision region of the transmitted point.

Comment: @MBaz Can you give me any hints? I have no idea what's wrong here.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what else to say -- I've answered two or three related questions already. I don't mean to be rude, but have you read one or two textbooks on the subject? Haykin and Sklar are widely available and very approachable. "There are no shortcuts to understanding digital communications" -- me.

Comment: @MBaz Anyway, thank you for your reply.